# How can I count records with equal value (text) in one specific column in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having a problem with counting records with same value in column.

I'm working on project where I have to make a report based on number of diagnosis with same value per specific date.

I have a table Diagnosis in which I have column Diagnosis_name and there I have some text values.

How can I make a report which counts all records with same values on specific date?

Answer (score 2):

```
select date, diag, count(*)
from table1
group by date, diag
```

Comment: Thank you, I also tried something like this, but I had parts of some other code and problem was with that. 

I have to make another report, it's a little bit complicated than this. I will write it here if I encounter any problems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's related  about hospital accomodation for new patients. 

I have a table named "Rooms", in which Ia have all needed columns, I also have columns Free_beds and occupied_beds for 8 different rooms. 

I also have table "Patient_reception" in which i have foreign key Room_number which is primary key in "Rooms" table.

I need to decrease number of available beds and increase number of occupied beds in table "Rooms" every time I enter a record with specific room in "Patient_reception" table.

As much as i know that should be done with triggers but i don't know if it can be done in access